# Why can't a python script find this module without stating 'python' from cmd explicitly?

Tags: python, module

Can someone explain why python doesn't find the module without explicitly typing python before the script? I've included python in my path and was under the impression that if the environment could interpret the script command/executes with python (giving the Traceback) then it should be no different than explicitly stating python?

The module is installed (verified by pip w/ pywin32 and pypiwin32).

```
>makereport.py --h
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xbbld7i\Documents\ISD\EH\makereport.py", line 9, in <module>
    import win32com.client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'

>python makereport.py --h
usage: makereport.py [-h] [-r REPORT] issues [issues ...]

positional arguments:
  issues                A list of the issues - omit commas.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -r REPORT, --report REPORT
                        The absolute path to the report to save -or- the
                        relative path from the current working directory.
```

Comment: I suspect the file type association of extension `.py`  may point to a different Python installation, in which `win32com` is not installed.